# Invalid expression term '['

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have written a regular expression for validating email and the regular expression is like this. But it is giving me the error of invalid expression term in the regex string after the '@' part.Below is the regex string.

```
/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
```

Thanks

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xOTII3/1  - look like it work

Comment: OP, please show exact code that U R using, because for both @degr and me it's working fine in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is working fine.

You don't need to escape char other than `[` or `]` inside a set. Use `[\w-.]`, not `[\w-\.]` (just an optimization).

**Additional note**

If you're using `var re = new RegExp("...")` instead of `var re = /.../` you need to escape backslashes or it won't works :

```js
// Works
var re = /^([\w-.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
console.log(re.test('marty@bbtf.com'));

// Also works
re = new RegExp("^([\\w-.]+@([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]{2,4})?$");
console.log(re.test('marty@bbtf.com'));

// Does NOT work
re = new RegExp("^([\w-.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$");
console.log(re.test('marty@bbtf.com'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex works fine. You need to **escape special symbols**. Like **`[`** to **`\[`** You could use a function for that:

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Comment: you need no do it, it work fine just with `/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/.test("adsasdf@asdas.com")`

Comment: @degr indeed it does. I didn't fully read his regEx. So then problem would be in the code he uses, I guess